# Workflow not appearing in Web Service hub

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm following through with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FweXOXRfy2Y) tutorial on setting up a web service to informatica, however despite following the instructions exactly the workflow does not appear in the web services hub in either valid or invalid.

On the workflow manager, the workflow has got Web Services Enabled and configured  (I can see the web service hub in the list), i've checked the visible and runnable options, still no luck.  I even created the mapping exactly the same as she did (using the manual Create Web Service Definition rather than import WSDL).

Other than setting these options is there anything else you have to do just to expose the workflow to the hub?  Just looking to see if the tutorial missed something really obvious which i've not done (the workflow shows a little blue icon next to it which i guess means it's set up for web services).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue we were facing was nothing to do with the set up of the mapping or workflow, all of which were correct.  After checking the logs in informatica we noticed a user login error.

Turns out there was no user created for the Web Services Hub, meaning it wasn't authenticating and returning the services.  Once this was fixed the valid web services appeared.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm if you have checked the options 'Visible' and 'Runnable' in Webservices config in workflow manager?

thanks.

Comment: Hi, yeah we checked this, actually the problem was somewhat simpler, i'll post it as an answer